# How to change order of symfony form elements?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have simple form `MyForm1`:

```
class MyForm1 extends Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('field1', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Field1'
        ])

        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Save',
        ]);
    }
}
```

and form `MyForm2` that is inherited from `MyForm1`

```
class MyForm2 extends MyForm1
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('field2', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Field2'
        ])
    }
}
```

and template

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

When I display `MyForm2`, `save` button is displayed before `field2`. How I can change order of elements? I know that I can remove and add this button again. Or call render function for every element in template. But I want just to set render indexes for elements. Suppose that it will take less time. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Symfony 5.3](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-form-field-sorting) you can use [`priority` attribute](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#priority) on any form field to drive the rendering order.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion the order of your form fields is something related to the view, not the model. So you should display manually your form in your view, fields by fields.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
   {{ form_row(form.field1)
   {{ form_row(form.field2)
   {{ form_row(form.save)
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about it. It's my laziness, it will require to make changes in form and template :)

Comment: Manually order form field in display could be not a good solution if we create form type using classes as causing the View (Twig) coupled with the Form Type. So in case removing some field from the type, we could get unexpected result if forgot to modify the View.

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyForm1 extends Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $this->buildFields($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Save',
        ]);
    }

    public function buildFields(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('field1', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Field1'
        ])
    }
}

class MyForm2 extends MyForm1
{
    // You can actually completely skip this method
    /*public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }*/

    public function buildFields(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildFields(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options);
        $builder->add('field2', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Field2'
        ]);
    }
}
```

You can also add `buildSubmit` in the same fashion if you need.